# Apply Chi-Squared Test in R on more than 5 variables and find the p-values

Tags: r, chi-squared

I am new to Chi-Squared Test. I have a database with lots of categorical variable.

Sample database with few variables are:

[image]

I want to apply the CHi-Squared test in R and want to find the p-values of all these categorical variable. Based on that i will rank my variables and delete the least important variables.

Can you advise me that how can i find the p-values of all the above variables in R.

As i know that Chi-Square can only be applied on 2 categorical variables but i have many categorical variables. How can do this?

Comment: I not sure if the Chi square test is the correct for your data. Can you clarify what your hypothesis which you are trying to test?  Also before asking a new question maybe you should review this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers

Comment: I have about 90 categorical variables and want to remove least important variables which does not have importance in the dataset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `lapply` to do repeated tasks, here a chi-squared test on multiple columns of a data frame with the first column.

```
CHIS <- lapply(data[,-1], function(x) chisq.test(data[,1], x)); CHIS
```

The result is a list, which can be combined in a nicer viewable format using `do.call` and `rbind`.

```
do.call(rbind, CHIS)[,c(1,3)]
   statistic    parameter p.value  
X1 0.08680556   1         0.7682782
X2 0.9695384    1         0.3247953
X3 9.464545e-31 1         1        
X4 0.9695384    1         0.3247953
X5 0.78125      1         0.3767591
```

Or perhaps using the `tidy` function from **broom**.

```
library(broom)

do.call(rbind, lapply(CHIS, tidy))

# A tibble: 5 x 4
  statistic p.value parameter method                                                      
*     <dbl>   <dbl>     <int> <chr>                                                       
1  8.68e- 2   0.768         1 Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction
2  9.70e- 1   0.325         1 Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction
3  9.46e-31   1.00          1 Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction
4  9.70e- 1   0.325         1 Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction
5  7.81e- 1   0.377         1 Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction
```

But unfortunately the names disappear. The `rbindlist` function from **data.table** has an optional `idcol` argument to preserve the names from the original list.

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(lapply(CHIS, tidy), idcol=TRUE)

   .id    statistic   p.value parameter
1:  X1 8.680556e-02 0.7682782         1
2:  X2 9.695384e-01 0.3247953         1
3:  X3 9.464545e-31 1.0000000         1
4:  X4 9.695384e-01 0.3247953         1
5:  X5 7.812500e-01 0.3767591         1
```

---

**Reproducible example**:

```
nvars=5; nrows=50
set.seed(123)
X <- data.frame(matrix(sample(c(0,1), size=nrows*nvars, replace=TRUE), nc=nvars))
data <- data.frame(AppCategory=c(rep("Benign", 20), rep("Malware", 30)), X)
str(data)
```

---

```
'data.frame':   50 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ AppCategory: Factor w/ 2 levels "Benign","Malware": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ X1         : num  0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 ...
 $ X2         : num  1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 ...
 $ X3         : num  0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 ...
 $ X4         : num  0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ X5         : num  1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Is there any way to Sort these based on the p-values because i have 90 variables. 
do.call(rbind, CHIS)[,c(1,3)]

Comment: `%>% dplyr::arrange(p.value)`

Answer (score 0):

First review all the details here: [performing a chi square test across multiple variables and extracting the relevant p value in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26107287/performing-a-chi-square-test-across-multiple-variables-and-extracting-the-releva/55543378)
Then see similar solution code below:

```
> # Assuming your dataframe is something like: 
> x1 <- sample(1:7,5,replace = F)
> x2 <- sample(2:7,5,replace = T)
> x3 <- sample(1:6,5,replace = T)
> x4 <- sample(3:8,5,replace = T)
> y <- sample(1:100,5,replace = F)
> df <- data.frame(cbind(x1,x2,x3,x4,y))
> ?sample
> mapply(function(x, y) chisq.test(x, y)$p.value, df[, -5], MoreArgs=list(df[,5]))
       x1        x2        x3        x4 
0.2202206 0.2202206 0.2872975 0.2414365 
# Note this is just a schema - you will need to adapt & align statistical nuances...
```