# how to calculate cross tabs between all variables with chi square calculation using R

Tags: r

My data example

```
cross=structure(list(a = c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), b = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), c = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L
), d = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), e = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), f = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), g = c(NA, 
1L, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 
NA), h = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), i = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), j = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), k = c(2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, NA, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), l = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), m = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), n = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), xxx = c(2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L))
```

I need  perform cross tab between all categorical variables
I.E.

```
a vs b
a vs c
...
d vs c
m vs n
```

and so on

i tried use `table` command ,but it provided not result that i need,cause i need also calculation of the chi-square test . That why ideally desired result for  me would be like this

```
b       total
        1   2   
a   1   42  54  96
    2   40  35  75
total   82  89  171
```

and p-value for chi-square

```
Value(empirical)    df       p-value
chi-square  1,549   1   0,213
```

How to do   crosstab between combinations of variables at once and get similar output results? Namely, the table  and the chi-square statistics for it.

Grateful for any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [performing a chi square test across multiple variables and extracting the relevant p value in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26107287/performing-a-chi-square-test-across-multiple-variables-and-extracting-the-releva)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get all combinations of column names (there will be 105 combinations of 2 columns if you are starting with 15 columns) you can use the `combn` function:

```r
cmb <- combn(names(cross), 2)
```

You can use this to get a contingency table for each column pair using `apply`:

```
tabs <- apply(cmb, 2, function(x) table(cross[[x[1]]], cross[[x[2]]]))
```

This then allows you to calculate your p values using `sapply`. With the data you provided, Chi square tests throw an error due to the small numbers involved, which invalidate the assumptions of the test. We can use the Fisher Exact test instead in this situation, though if your own data is much larger you may wish to stick to Chi Square.

```
pvals <- sapply(tabs, function(x) {
  if(all(dim(x) == c(2, 2))) fisher.test(x)$p.val else NA
  })
```

Finally, we can create a results data frame with the two columns compared, and the p value for the ratio of proportions between each two columns. Note that depending on your use case, your threshold for significance should be lowered to account for multiple hypothesis testing, as one would expect to have around 5 'significant' p values of < 0.05 purely by chance.

```r
data.frame(col1 = cmb[1,], col2 = cmb[2,], pval = pvals)
#>     col1 col2         pval
#> 1      a    b 1.0000000000
#> 2      a    c 1.0000000000
#> 3      a    d           NA
#> 4      a    e 1.0000000000
#> 5      a    f 0.2682072829
#> 6      a    g 1.0000000000
#> 7      a    h 0.5294117647
#> 8      a    i 0.6148459384
#> 9      a    j           NA
#> 10     a    k 0.6000323206
#> 11     a    l 0.6043956044
#> 12     a    m 0.5927601810
#> 13     a    n 1.0000000000
#> 14     a  xxx 1.0000000000
#> 15     b    c 0.0114379085
#> 16     b    d           NA
#> 17     b    e 1.0000000000
#> 18     b    f 0.3259803922
#> 19     b    g 1.0000000000
#> 20     b    h 0.4967320261
#> 21     b    i 1.0000000000
#> 22     b    j           NA
#> 23     b    k 0.2800581771
#> 24     b    l 0.2335164835
#> 25     b    m 0.6220691074
#> 26     b    n 1.0000000000
#> 27     b  xxx 1.0000000000
#> 28     c    d           NA
#> 29     c    e 1.0000000000
#> 30     c    f 1.0000000000
#> 31     c    g 0.4285714286
#> 32     c    h 1.0000000000
#> 33     c    i 1.0000000000
#> 34     c    j           NA
#> 35     c    k 0.5378151261
#> 36     c    l 0.5164835165
#> 37     c    m 0.1029411765
#> 38     c    n 0.2605042017
#> 39     c  xxx 0.2450980392
#> 40     d    e           NA
#> 41     d    f           NA
#> 42     d    g           NA
#> 43     d    h           NA
#> 44     d    i           NA
#> 45     d    j           NA
#> 46     d    k           NA
#> 47     d    l           NA
#> 48     d    m           NA
#> 49     d    n           NA
#> 50     d  xxx           NA
#> 51     e    f 0.2800581771
#> 52     e    g 0.4285714286
#> 53     e    h 0.5147058824
#> 54     e    i 0.5840336134
#> 55     e    j           NA
#> 56     e    k 1.0000000000
#> 57     e    l 0.6043956044
#> 58     e    m 0.0076173826
#> 59     e    n 0.0631868132
#> 60     e  xxx 0.0276341306
#> 61     f    g 0.4285714286
#> 62     f    h 1.0000000000
#> 63     f    i 0.5827497666
#> 64     f    j           NA
#> 65     f    k 1.0000000000
#> 66     f    l 1.0000000000
#> 67     f    m 1.0000000000
#> 68     f    n 0.6000323206
#> 69     f  xxx 1.0000000000
#> 70     g    h 1.0000000000
#> 71     g    i 1.0000000000
#> 72     g    j           NA
#> 73     g    k 1.0000000000
#> 74     g    l 1.0000000000
#> 75     g    m 0.4285714286
#> 76     g    n 1.0000000000
#> 77     g  xxx 1.0000000000
#> 78     h    i 0.4901960784
#> 79     h    j           NA
#> 80     h    k 1.0000000000
#> 81     h    l 0.4500000000
#> 82     h    m 0.4852941176
#> 83     h    n 1.0000000000
#> 84     h  xxx 0.5294117647
#> 85     i    j           NA
#> 86     i    k 0.2605042017
#> 87     i    l 0.2445054945
#> 88     i    m 1.0000000000
#> 89     i    n 0.6000323206
#> 90     i  xxx 1.0000000000
#> 91     j    k           NA
#> 92     j    l           NA
#> 93     j    m           NA
#> 94     j    n           NA
#> 95     j  xxx           NA
#> 96     k    l 0.5164835165
#> 97     k    m 1.0000000000
#> 98     k    n 0.5467032967
#> 99     k  xxx 0.6000323206
#> 100    l    m 0.2351648352
#> 101    l    n 0.1538461538
#> 102    l  xxx 0.0631868132
#> 103    m    n 0.0013736264
#> 104    m  xxx 0.0005656109
#> 105    n  xxx 0.0001616031
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>